# How to block a "Comma" in HTML input with Firefox browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

How to block a "Comma" in HTML input with Firefox browser?

This Javascript code works for Opera Browser:

```
          // ----- Block the "COMMA" for all inputs.
     $(document).keydown(function(e) {
         var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
         if(keyCode==188){
             //  alert("COMMA has been pressed on the keyboard...") ;
             e.preventDefault();   // Note, "preventDefault" has to be within "if".
         }

     });
```

Comment: Both `keyCode` and `which` are deprecated, use the standard `key` property of the event object insteaad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`keyCode` [has been deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode). Use `e.key` instead.

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if (e.key === ',') {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
})
```

Comment: This  e.key  Javascript code works for Opera Browser and MS Edge, but NOT firefox...

Comment: @Terry Please check your code and the browser cache, `key` has been working in Firefox since 2013.

Comment: Thanks Alk!  Your answer was very close to what worked.

Comment: No problem. If you are worried about the arrow functions, [they have been supported since Firefox22](https://caniuse.com/arrow-functions).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for Firefox and 2 other browsers:

```
           // ----- Block the "COMMA" for all inputs.
     document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
               if (e.key === ',') {
                   e.preventDefault();
                   return false;
               }
            })
```

---

Thanks

Comment: This 1st line is jQuery and also works.         $(document).keydown(function(e)